# iOS 8 AutoLayout scrollview scrolls horizontally on iPhone 6 plus

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, iphone-6-plus

I do have an App for iOS and while adapting all the UI to auto layout an size classes to support the new iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus i faced a weird issue... al my scrolls view work fine in iPhone 4s, 5, 5s and 6... in iPhone 6 plus they are not scrolling only vertically but also horizontally... like if the content size of the scroll view where a couple of pixel wider than the view itself (so it move horizontally of a couple of pixel and then it bounce).
I do not understand why is this happening...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally found a proper way to let it work... I did it this way:

View hierarchy:
- UIView (Main view)
    - UIScrollView (which I wan of the same exact size of the Main view)
        - UIView (Container View containing all the stuff to be displayed in the scroll view)

Constraints:

Containar View:
- width equals to the one of the Main View
- 0 leadin, trailing, top and bottom margin with superview (which is the Scroll View)

UIScrollView:
- width equals to the one of the Main View
- center view on X axis horizontally (center X)
- 0 top an bottom margin with superview

Comment: This did not work for me. I'm also not understanding why the above would work because content view controls the UIScrollView yet you set the width of UIScrollView

Comment: My issue I guess was caused by a -16 constraint in leading and trailing space for the scrollview to its superview which is added by default by Interface Builder if I say I want the scroll view to be of the same size of the window (not same width... it is added if I drag the border of the scrollview to mach the ones of the window). Putting the constraint to the width of the scroll view and centering it by X gave me a consistent set of constraints for how I wanted the scrollview to looks like

Comment: @kgaidis - iOS does funky stuff to make scrollviews work with autolayout: [Apple tech note UIScrollView And Autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2154/_index.html)  An alternative, is to directly set UIScrollView.contentSize yourself in code, after layout has completed. From the tech note, it seems that the constraints on the inner content don't do what you would think they do - they are not what determines the size of the scrolled region.